# Counting NaN in Pandas Dataframe but omitting the leading ones

Tags: python, pandas

I want to count the NaN for each column contained in a dataframe but omitting the leading NaNs.

So my dataframe has the following structure:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame({'Date': 
pd.date_range(pd.datetime.today().strftime("%m/%d/%Y"),periods=10).tolist(),
             'Col1': [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,4,5,6,7,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
             'Col2': [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,4,5,6,7,8,9,np.nan],  
             'Col3': [np.nan,2,3,4,np.nan,6,7,8,9,np.nan] })
df
        Date  Col1  Col2  Col3
0 2019-08-16   NaN   NaN   NaN
1 2019-08-17   NaN   NaN   2.0
2 2019-08-18   NaN   NaN   3.0
3 2019-08-19   4.0   4.0   4.0
4 2019-08-20   5.0   5.0   NaN
5 2019-08-21   6.0   6.0   6.0
6 2019-08-22   7.0   7.0   7.0
7 2019-08-23   NaN   8.0   8.0
8 2019-08-24   NaN   9.0   9.0
9 2019-08-25   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

The desired output should be a dataframe, sth. like:

```
Col1  Col2  Col3
  3     1     2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First filter all columns without first by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and then subtract non nans values with repalce mising values by `NaN`s with [`DataFrame.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.count.html) with count all non nans values:

```
df1 = df.iloc[:, 1:]
a =  df1.ffill().count() - df1.count()
```

Or:

```
df1 = df.iloc[:, 1:]
a = df1.isna().sum() - df1.ffill().isna().sum()
```

Or:

```
df1 = df.iloc[:, 1:]
a = df1.mask(df1.ffill().isna(), 1).isna().sum()
```

---

```
print (a)

Col1    3
Col2    1
Col3    2
dtype: int64
```

Last if need one row DataFrame:

```
df1 = a.to_frame(0).T
print (df1)
   Col1  Col2  Col3
0     3     1     2
```

Comment: I think OP wants to drop the first contiguous group of nans, not first nan in each group.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem - not sure, so ask OP in comments under question

Comment: @jezrael: Indeed I want to drop the first contiguous group of NaNs. However, I just saw that df1.ffill() just fills does that. If fills only the NaNs after the first group of contiguous NaNs.

Answer (score 1):

Your df example doesn't match your output example.

Setup:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Date': 
pd.date_range(pd.datetime.today().strftime("%m/%d/%Y"),periods=10).tolist(),
             'Col1': [np.nan,np.nan ,np.nan,4,5,6,7,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
             'Col2': [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,4,5,6,7,8,9,np.nan],  
             'Col3': [np.nan,2,3,4,np.nan,6,7,8,9,np.nan] })
```

Solution:

```
df.iloc[:,1:].apply(lambda x: x.iloc[x.notna().idxmax():].isna().sum())
Col1    3
Col2    1
Col3    2
dtype: int64
```

As @jezrael pointed out, this solution may not work if all the values in a column is nan.

Jezrael's solution is more elegant. Please use his.

Comment: Depending on what OP means, this may not work if the first patch of `nan`s has more than one `nan` and starts after the first row.

Comment: I commented under the assumption that OP wants to count all nan's except those occurring in the first group. (Maybe I'm wrong here). If so, setting `.iloc[0,Col1]` to one produces the count of `5` nans in the first column, while I am guessing it should be three.

Comment: I think by 'leading nans', he means any consecutive nans start from the first row. Let's see the OP's response.

Comment: @jezrael, thanks for the good catch. Have updated my solution for my exercise and your solution is much more elegant.

Comment: Removed thanks @jezrael. I'm glad I learnt something new today from you. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. Please if you have similar problem with me, let me know... I think sometimes in future...

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use `label` function from `scipy.ndimage` to locate all contiguous patches of `nan`s, then count entries with label exceeding `1`.

```
from scipy.ndimage import label
res = df.isnull().apply(lambda s: (label(s)[0] > 1).sum())
# Date    0
# Col1    3
# Col2    1
# Col3    2
```